# Seek Bar Causing Crash

Tags: android, seekbar

So I am new to android and am trying to implement a seek bar. In my onCreate method for my main activity I call this method.

```
public void seekbar(){
    seek_bar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
    text_view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seekTextView);
    text_view.setText(seek_bar.getProgress());

    seek_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
            new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
                int progress_value;
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                    progress_value = i;
                    text_view.setText(i);
                }
                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"SeekBar in StartTracking",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    text_view.setText(progress_value);
                }
            }

    );
}
```

If I comment the call out my app loads fine but if I leave it in the app crashed straight away. Can anyone explain why this is happening as I can't see what's wrong. Will add more code if necessary too

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you inflated your seekbar, my calling layoutInflator or by setting the contentView on the appropriate layout , it seems to be the case that

```
seek_bar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
```

is returning null and it will create an exception when calling

```
seek_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener
```

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean how is it returning null? 
At the top  of my glass I have this 
private static SeekBar seek_bar; 
In my xml the ID of my Seek Bar is seekbar2 (I know bad name but will change).
So I don't get how null is returned?